# vim: Selectively replacing brackets in a file

Tags: regex, vim

I have following text file:

```
A(B C)
D(E F)
A(G 
H 
I)
```

I want to convert this to:

```
modifiedA{B C}
D(E F)
modifiedA{G 
H
I}
```

Usually, I would use `s/A(/modifiedA\{/g` and `s/)/}/g`.

Since I don't want to touch the line with `D(E F)`, this won't work.

Thank you for your comments/help.

Update:

1. The answer should not require human intervention and should be scalable. Hence, using `c` instead of `g` is not an option.
2. Also note that `A()` can be spread across multiple lines.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to match a multiline pattern we need `\_.\{-}` which means non-greedy regex search:

```
:%s/\(A\)(\(\_.\{-}\))/modified\1{\2}

\( ................ start of a regex group
\) ................ end of a regex group
\_.\{-} ........... non-greedy regex
\1 ................ back reference to the regex group 1
```

Using `very magic option` see `:h \v`.

```
%s/\v(A)\((\w \_.{-})\)/modified\1{\2}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do it by recording and replaying a vim macro: (for example, `q`):

Recording:

```
qq/A(<Enter>%%r{``r}q
```

Replaying:

```
99@q
```

This works as long as the `(...)` for A are well paired. It works even in nesting cases:

[image]

Answer (score 0):

*This was an answer to the first version of the question.*

The `substitute` command supports the flag `c` for confirmation:

```
[c] Confirm each substitution.  Vim highlights the matching string (with
|hl-IncSearch|).  You can type:             *:s_c*
    'y'     to substitute this match
    'l'     to substitute this match and then quit ("last")
    'n'     to skip this match
    <Esc>   to quit substituting
    'a'     to substitute this and all remaining matches {not in Vi}
    'q'     to quit substituting {not in Vi}
    CTRL-E  to scroll the screen up {not in Vi, not available when
        compiled without the |+insert_expand| feature}
    CTRL-Y  to scroll the screen down {not in Vi, not available when
        compiled without the |+insert_expand| feature}
If the 'edcompatible' option is on, Vim remembers the [c] flag and
toggles it each time you use it, but resets it when you give a new
search pattern.
{not in Vi: highlighting of the match, other responses than 'y' or 'n'}
```

See

```
:help :s_flags
```

Comment: Thank you. I should have added that I want to automate the process for multiple files. This method is not scalable.

Comment: OK, now that you've edited the question, my answer doesn't make sense any more :-/ but what would be the logic behind you wanted to replace `A(B C)`, but not `D(E F)`?

Comment: I am writing a parser which takes my own text format and outputs `markdown` for further processing by `pandoc`. There is a [tufte-markdown](https://github.com/duzyn/tufte-markdown) utility. I am trying to mimic its functionality using vim which looks simpler to me.I am sorry for the change in the question. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:
`:%s/\(A\)(\(B C\))/modified\1{\2}/g | %s/\(A\)(\(G\)/modified\1{\2}/g | %s/\(I\))/\1}/g`

Let's break it down:

- `:s`: abbrevation for the `:substitute` command.
- `/`: start of the pattern.
- `\(A\)`: captures 'A' in the first capture group.
- `(`: a literal '('
- `\(B C\)`: captures 'B C' in the second capture group.
- `)`: a literal ')'
- `/`: end of the pattern. Start of the substitution.
- `\1`: backreference to the first capture group ('A').
- `{\2}`: backreference to the second capture group ('B C') surrounded by literal braces.
- `/g`: end of substition and the flag 'g' makes the substitution apply multiple times per line.

The '|'s between the commands make them execute one after another automatically.

*Note that this answer relies on 'A', 'D' and 'I' being literals. Otherwise they could include the following parenthesed text. If you are working with more complex text, I suggest you do multiple substitutions rather than single command.*

See also:
`:help :|`
`:help pattern.txt`
`:help usr_27.txt`